# Automatic installation of iftex.sty does not work on Texmaker

Tags: packages, texmaker, installing, missing

I'm using Texmaker and so far, when there isn't a specific package, Texmaker was able to install it by asking me if I want to install it (a window with the butttom Install appeared).

The same happens for iftex.sty, but, after I clicked on Install, the Pdf file is not created and, if I compile again, the situation remains the same.

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

PS: in the folder MiKTeX... there is a file called iftex.sty.

Comment: this can sometimes happen if packages are rearranged. The package database from miktex gets then confused. Go to the miktex console and run in the menu "tasks" the task "update package database". Do it in user *and* admin mode. Check also in both modes for updates.

Comment: Hello @UlrikeFischer thank you for your suggestion. I did it and now another error appears Undefined control sequence "\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks". I'm trying to run the rtsched file https://ctan.org/pkg/rtsched?lang=en

Comment: don't use pdflatex if your code use pstricks. pstricks requires latex + dvips.